# C++ - Two names in class declaration (macros)

Tags: c++, class, macros

I'm working on existing C++ code, which is using a kind of API.
While browsing the code I found a strange syntax that I saw now for the first time and I can't figure out what it does or how such is called.

It goes like this:

```
class KINDA_API foobar : public foo {
    // Some class declarations
};
```

Everything after foobar is understandable for me. But what means that KINDA_API? What does this do? Is that any kind of advanced derivation or something like that?
Maybe there is any other Thread that answers this, and I also searched for it, but I don't even know how this is called ^^'

Comment: It's probably a macro; have you searched the source for a definition?

Comment: btw, no need for the `[solved]` marker -- once you accept an answer, that can be seen in the list of questions.

Comment: Ah, alright. It's my first question here ^^ I'll leave it like it is now but gonna keep it in mind for the next time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually when you see OMGWFT_API declarations in this exact way, this is a 'magic switch' for building a library in correct "mode":

- static linking - OMGWFT_API replaced by "" (empty string)
- dynamic linking - DLL - OMGWFT_API replaced by declspec(dllexport)
- dynamic linking - EXE - OMGWFT_API replaced by declspec(dllimport)

i.e.

```
#ifdef BUILD_ME_AS_STATICLIB
#define OMGWFT_API
#else
#ifdef BUILD_ME_AS_DLL
#define OMGWFT_API declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define OMGWFT_API declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#endif
```

This is of course just an sketch of example, but I think you get the point now. Keywords are taken from MSVC not GCC< because I accidentially happen to remember them.

The "BUILD_ME_AS...." macros would be then defined via project options or -D command line switch.

However, it the OMGWFT_API can be set to have any meaning, so be sure to grep/search for a #define that sets this.

Comment: That is exactly the same that I also found in my code :) That explains it really good. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is a `#define`-d macro that does some "magic" before compile.

Comment: Woah, you guys answer extremely fast, I even had no time to respond to Charles... Yes, that seems to be it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you look through the existing call you are likely to find somthing like:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define KINDA_API <windows specific attribute>
#elif __linux
#define KINDA_API <linux specific attribute>
```

etc...

These macros are more likely conditioned on compilers and/or their versions rather than operating system but you get the idea...